# Regular expression to find both non-null and NULL values

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

My stored procedure is using regular expression as a parameter to filter a set of rows:

```
DECLARE @filter = '%'

SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
WHERE ColumnA LIKE @filter
```

Value '%' extracts all non-null values of ColumnA. However I need to extract both non-null AND null values.

The idea of using second condition (and ColumnA is NULL) is not suitable as the filter shall come as a single parameter.

It would be great to find if there any regex expression which can cover NULL values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support Regex, only it's own (more limited) pattern matching.

*Normally* I wouldn't recommend this answer, however, as you have a leading wild card already performance will be out the window. Assuming you want `'%'` to return every row, you *could* do:

```
DECLARE @Filter = '%';

SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE ISNULL(ColumnA,'|') LIKE @Filter;
```

Note, however, that if you *might* not be using leading wild cards this is a really bad idea; it'll kill performance. If that is the case, then use Lukasz's solution, and not this one.

Comment: So not using `@Filter` in the query is the answer?

Comment: Clearly the caffeine had not kicked in yet, thanks @HABO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I have tested it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `OR` condition:

```
DECLARE @filter = '%'
SELECT * FROM TableA 
where ColumnA like @filter OR @filter = '%'
```

Comment: Just thinking, might want to make this a dynamic statement to avoid bad query plan caching.

Comment: The `and columnA is null` is redundant.  `columnA like @filter` covers non-nulls, and `@filter = '%'` covers anything regardless of the value (or lack of) in `ColumnA`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, you are right. Thanks for spotting it